# lambda function in sorted dictionary list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension

I have the following dictionary:

```
student_loan_portfolio = {
    'loan1': {'rate': .078, 'balance': 1000, 'payment': 100, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan2': {'rate': .0645, 'balance': 10, 'payment': 5, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan3': {'rate': .0871, 'balance': 250, 'payment': 60, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan4': {'rate': .0842, 'balance': 200, 'payment': 37, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan5': {'rate': .054, 'balance': 409, 'payment': 49, 'prepayment': 0},
    'loan6': {'rate': .055, 'balance': 350, 'payment': 50, 'prepayment': 0}
}
```

I would like to iterate through the containing dictionary (with keys loan1 through loan6) in order of the key containing the dictionary with the highest 'rate' value in its respective nested dictionary. That is, I would like to iterate in order of loan3, loan4, loan1, loan2, loan6, loan5

Thanks to @Jame Sharp the easiest way to do this that I know is:

```
for k,v in sorted(student_loan_portfolio.items(), key=lambda (k,v): v['rate'], reverse=True):
```

I am now reading about lambda and cannot really understand exactly how and why this works.
First, v['rate'] I believe is returning the value of those dictionary keys.  But its seems like it should be some kind of syntax error.  what is v['rate'] referencing and what is the logic behind the syntax?

On a related note, why, do we have to specify the inputs to the lambda function as a tuple?

And how are the following cases different?

```
#1

>>>f = lambda x,y,z:x + y + z
>>>f(1,2,3)

#6

>>>f = lambda (x,y,z): x + y + z
>>>f(1,2,3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    f(1,2,3)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: the second one expects a packed input with 3 values? `f((1,2,3))`

Comment: Second format not valid in Python 3, FYI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `items()` method on `student_loan_portfolio.items()` returns a list of key/value tuples.  So it returns something like `[ ('loan1', dictOfLoan1), ('loan2', dictOfLoan2), ...]`.  The lambda accepts this tuple as an argument, and reads the "rate" item from the value dict (i.e., it reads `dictOfLoan1['rate']`, `dictOfLoan2['rate']`, etc.).

You could achieve the same effect by using, instead of the lambda you have, `lambda item: item[1]['rate']`.  `item` is a tuple `(key, value)`, so `item[1]` is the value.

The difference between your two lambda examples is that the first one accepts three arguments, while the second accepts a single argument which is a three-element tuple.  The ability to define a function which accepts tuples as arguments but unpacks their contents into separate local variables was a quirk of Python that was removed in Python 3 (see [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)).

Comment: Ok thanks @BrenBarn. I did some more experimentation and so the reason v['rate'] is not a syntax error is because v is a dictionary, right?

Comment: @user1816858: Yes, basically.  You have a dictionary whose values are also dictionaries.  (If it weren't a dictionary, it still wouldn't be a *syntax* error, but you would get an error if it didn't support item access using `[]`.)

Answer (score 8):

`lambda (k,v): v['rate']` is a function that takes a single argument (a 2-tuple), and returns the `'rate'` key of the second entry in the tuple. It is equivalent to `lambda t: t[1]['rate']`

`lambda x,y,z:x + y + z` is a function which takes 3 values and returns their sum.

`lambda (x,y,z): x + y + z` is a function that takes 1 value (a 3-tuple), and returns the sum of its elements.